# What is the runtime of this nested for loop?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, runtime, big-o

```
for i = 1 to n   
  for j = 1 to i - 1
```

Is the runtime of this O(n^2)?
Is there a good way to visualize things when approaching these types of problems to find the right answer?

Answer (score 3):

Inner loop executes

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 +...n-1 = n*(n-1)/2 times
```

using formula for arithmetic progression sum, so overall compexity is O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Each for loop is O(n), two for loops O(n)*O(n) = O(n^2)

Check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6xkbGLQesk&t=1s) out. The author explains good ways to approach figuring out runtimes.